# Edit Word content, Replace Keyword with other text with PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, ms-word, decode

I want to edit a file which extension is .doc
This file contains some keywords such as:

```
<<Customer>>
<<DateStart>>
ecc.
```

Now I want to read the content of the file, edit it and then put it in new word.

I try in this way:

```
header ("Content-Type: application/msword; ");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=new.doc");

$filename='a.doc';
$key = "«Customer»";
$fc=file($filename);

$f=fopen("'C:\Users\Ciro\Desktop\new.doc","w");
foreach($fc as $line){
  if (strpos($line,$key))
    $line=str_replace($key,"some new text",$line);
  file_put_contents($f,$line); 
}
fclose($f);
fclose($fc);
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I use Windows. Those solutions are under Linux. Can I use COM to do what I what?

Comment: Not true! PhpLiveDocX is part of Zend, which is available for Windows, for free.

Answer (score 0):

The following line was wrong, it had a misplaced `'`

```
f=fopen("C:\Users\Ciro\Desktop\new.doc","w");
```

Also, `DOC` files aren't simple `TXT` files because its content is encoded, if possible, convert it to a `TXT` file.

This is how a `DOC` file looks like to `PHP`

[image]

Basically, `PHP` cannot see what you see and you won't be able to achieve what you want, unless you convert the `DOC` file to a `RAW format`, like `TXT`.

**UPDATE:**

Try `catdoc`, which converts any .doc file into plain text. See the [catdoc homepage](http://www.wagner.pp.ru/~vitus/software/catdoc/)

Comment: I know it. Is There a way to get only the text?

Comment: How can I convert in a Raw format?

Comment: There is no support for catdoc under Windows